# What is are the advantages of a custom data structure?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

What's the need to go for defining and implementing **data structures** (e.g. `stack`) ourselves if they are already available in C++ **STL**?

What are the differences between the two implementations?

Comment: This questions is too broad to answer but you may want to look at this short video about why FB reimplemented string: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPR8h4-qZdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, implementing by your own an existing data structure is a useful exercise. You understand better what it does (so you can understand better what the standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) do). In particular, you understand better why [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is so important.

Then, there is a quality of implementation issue. The standard implementation might not be suitable for you.

Let me give an example. Indeed, [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is implementing a stack. It is a general-purpose implementation. Have you measured `sizeof(std::stack<char>)`? Have you benchmarked it, in the case of a million of stacks of 3.2 elements on average with a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)?

Perhaps in *your* case, you happen to know that you have millions of stacks of `char`-s (never <kbd>NUL</kbd>), and that 99% of them have less than 4 elements. With that additional knowledge, you probably should be able to implement something "better" than what the standard C++ stack provides. So `std::stack<char>` would work, but given that extra knowledge you'll be able to implement it differently. You still (for readability and maintenance) would use the same *methods* as in `std::stack<char>` - so your `WeirdSmallStackOfChar` would have a `push` method, etc. If (later during the project) you realize or that bigger stack might be useful (e.g. in 1% of cases) you'll reimplement your stack differently (e.g. if your code base grow to a million lines of C++ and you realize that you have quite often bigger stacks, you might "remove" your `WeirdSmallStackOfChar` class and add `typedef std::stack<char> WeirdSmallStackOfChar;` ....)

If you happen to know that *all* your stacks have less than 4 `char`-s and that `\0` is not valid in them, representing such "stack"-s as a `char w[4]` field is probably the wisest approach. It is fast and easy to code.

So, if performance and memory space matters, you might perhaps code something as weird as

```
class MyWeirdStackOfChars {
   bool small;
   union {
     std::stack<char>* bigstack;
     char smallstack[4];
   }
```

Of course, that is very incomplete. When `small` is true your implementation uses `smallstack`. For the 1% case where it is false, your implemention uses `bigstack`. The rest of `MyWeirdStackOfChars` is left as an exercise (not that easy) to the reader. Don't forget to follow the [rule of five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Ok, maybe the above example is not convincing. But what about `std::map<int,double>`? You might have millions of them, and you might know that 99.5% of them are smaller than 5. You obviously could optimize for that case. It is highly probable that representing small maps by an array of pairs of `int` & `double` is more efficient both in terms of memory and in terms of CPU time.

Sometimes, you even know that *all* your maps have less than 16 entries (and `std::map<int,double>` don't know that) and that the key is *never* 0. Then you might represent them differently. In that case, I guess that I am able to implement something much more efficient than what `std::map<int,double>`  provides (probably, because of [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) effects, an array of 16 entries with an `int` and a `double` is the fastest).

That is why any developer should know the classical algorithms (and have read some [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)), even if in many cases he would use existing containers. Be also aware of the [as-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule).

Comment: Flexibility, performance, maintainability, development time, robustness, etc... All these factors count in real life. You need to understand which are the dominant ones.

Answer (score 1):

STL implementation of Data Structures is **not perfect** for **every possible use case**.

I like the example of hash tables. I have been using STL implementation for a while, but I use it mainly for Competitive Programming contests.

Imagine that you are Google and you have **billions of dollars** in **resources destined to storing and accessing hash tables**. You would probably like to have the **best possible implementation** for the company use cases, since it will **save resources** and **make search faster** in general. 
Oh, and I forgot to mention that you also have some of the best engineers on the planet working for you (:

(This video is made by Kulukundis talking about the new hash table made by his team at Google )
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncHmEUmJZf4

Some other reasons that justify implementing your **own version** of Data Structures:

- Test your **understanding** of a **specific structure**.
- **Customize part** **of the structure to some peculiar use case**.
- Seek **better performance than STL** for a specific data structure.
- **Hating STL errors.**
- **Benchmarking** STL against some simple implementation.